# jQuery redirect after a set time of page loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

I'm wanting to create a redirect using jQuery.

What I want to do is if the page is loading for lets say 5 seconds I want it to redirect to another page.

```
function Redirect() {  
window.location="http://example.com/search.jsp; <-- Page being redirected from
} 
document.write("This page is unavailable at this time, You will be redirected to the home page in 5 seconds"); 
setTimeout('Redirect()', 5000);
```

but than load a different page after 5 seconds lets say it will be redirected to **NewSearch.jsp**

Comment: You forgot a close quote on your window.location... also window.location should equal the page you want to redirect to, not the current page. Of course, this will only work if the user has JS enabled. Not sure how this relates to jQuery at all, these are all vanilla JS functions.

Comment: the first parameter of setTimeout should be a function, not a string. like `setTimeout(function(){Redirect();}, 5000);`

Comment: Please mark an answer if it resolved your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
document.write("This page is unavailable at this time, You will be redirected to the home page in 5 seconds");

setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.href="http://example.com/search.jsp";
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
var unavailable = true;
$(window).load(function() {
    unavailable = false;
});

function redirect() {  
    window.location.href="http://example.com/search.jsp";
}

setTimeout(function() { 
    if (unavailable === true){
        redirect();
    }
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Why did I get a -1. His question isn't how to make my code work, it is how do I get my page to redirect if it doesn't load in 5 seconds.